# Calling CGI using javascript

Tags: javascript, cgi

I have one CGI using python and placed in server .Now i have one URL to call that CGI,in that url i need to pass value to update in database.So how can i pass value in that url using javascript. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and make a call `$.ajax("http://yourhost/someMethod?someParameter=someValue")`, but the real solution depends on the expected format of your URL, method, i.e. GET or POST, and so on.

Comment: Thanks skovalyov..But i am going access this is in an mobile ,in that ajax is not supported.IS any other option.

Comment: Then just open the URL invoking the method directly.